# Auto refresh file or directory in WebApplication

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are using a tree view to display all the files and directories in C:\ drive in  our web application.Now we have requirement for the directory / file list to intelligently refresh whenever any file changes in the tree. How can we achieve this in Web Application ?

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to receive notifications in a Windows app when a file or folder is modified, using [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). You would need to create a Windows Service to run that in.

The trouble is the web offers no straightforward way to pass this server based event up to you web client (except hacks like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)). Instead the web client would typically poll for updates. You can use AJAX to quietly refresh your file list in the browser, triggered by some javascript that fires an event periodically (use javascript setInterval() function).

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit tricky. First of all you will want to implement long polling or Push how it's popular to call it nowadays. Other way is polling, but polling sucks. There is a good async signaling framework for .Net called [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

Secondly you'd want to use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to monitor your folders.

Enjoy :)