# Why is an html src path still showing an image, after an AJAX call to Server-side deletes it?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, .net

In my web site, I have a partial CMS implemented. One of the functions the users will be able to accomplish is the uploading of various files to be linked in whichever pages they deem necessary. I am using AJAX and `System.IO` in C# on the server-side to give the users the ability to upload or delete files within a given directory.

In addition to this, there is a live preview of the page as they edit. All was going well until I tried to refresh the preview (with javascript) *after* a file that was already pathed-to, was deleted.

The path to a file that has just been deleted *should* show a broken link, but it still shows the correct picture instead (even though checking and manually refreshing the server-side directory, shows that it is, in fact, not there).

I saw this SO question here: [Auto refresh file or directory in WebApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711949/auto-refresh-file-or-directory-in-webapplication) but it doesn't appear to necessarily apply in my case (otherwise why wouldn't I have problems when adding a picture instead of just deleting one)?

I spent hours checking over my JavaScript/jQuery to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything, but it is all channeled through one function, when it comes to the refresh so it should work all the time or break all the time, not one or the other sometimes.

Does the picture still exist somewhere client-side, even after deleted from the server-side? (again, though, the `src` attribute of the `img` tag is pointing to a file that has been deleted with C# `File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/CMS Files/" + location + "/" + file));`

**The Ajax Function:**

```
function deleteFile(event) {
    var fileToDelete = event.parent().find(".fileDiv").text();
    var fileLocation = $("input#pageLocation").val();

    var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to permanently delete the file, \"" + fileToDelete + "\" from the \"" + fileLocation + "\" File Box?");

    if (confirmation) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AJAX Pages/Compute_Delete_File.cshtml",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: { location: fileLocation, file: fileToDelete },
            success: function (response) {
                refreshFileBoxes(); //<--Self made function that refreshes the boxes (again, using AJAX) that collect what files are in the directory. Funny that this part always reflects correctly, the existing files in the server-side directory.
                alert(response);
                updatePreview(); //<--This function recollects all the page data in an array of objects, and refreshes the preview accordingly.
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                alert("Oops! It appears there has been an AJAX error. You may need to refresh the page. Please save your work and refresh the page to see all files in the File Box.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Server-side code that the Ajax function points to:**

```
@{
    Layout = "";

    if (IsAjax)
    {
        var file = Request.Form["file"];
        var location = Request.Form["location"];

        File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/CMS Files/" + location + "/" + file));

@:The file "@file" has been deleted.
    }
    else
    {
        Context.RedirectLocal("~/");
    }
}
```

**HTML for the preview**

```
<div class="editPreview">
    <div id="Library" class="contentWrapper">
        <hr/>
        <p class="pageTitle">Library</p>
        <hr/>
        <div class="contentImageWrapper" sytle="max-width: 375px;">
            <img class="contentImgMedium" src="/CMS Files/Library/Okmulgee_Library.jpg" title="Okmulgee_Library.jpg" alt="Okmulgee_Library.jpg" />
        </div>
        <p class="contentParagraph" style=" text-align: center;">For more information about the Okmulgee Public Library, call (918)-756-1448.</p>
        <br/>
        <span class="contentText">Or visit their website at&nbsp;</span>
        <a class="contentLink" href="http://www.fakewebaddress.com" target="_blank">http://www.fakewebaddress.com</a>&nbsp;
        <br/>
        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Things you might need to know:**

I am in a C#.net web-pages environment (w/ WebMatrix)
I am willing to provide any more code needed, but the nature of all the file-pathing, makes a jsfiddle impossible, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is probably loading the file from the browser cache and displaying it, even though it no longer exists on the server.

If you want it removed from display in the current page, you can just remove the object from the current page and not have this problem.

---

Now, that you've added the HTML, if you want to make sure the image shows as broken, you can change the src on the `<img>` tag to something that will not exist:

```
$("#Library .contentImagbeWrapper img").attr({
    src: "bustedimg.jpg",
    title: "missing image",
    alt: "missing image"
});
```

It's your choice if you want `bustedimg.jpg` to be an actual image or not.  It could either be your own version of what a broken image should look like or it could be missing and the browser will do whatever it does for a broken image (some browsers show nothing).

Comment: @VoidKing - you would have to show us the relevant HTML in the page and identify which object it is that you want removed.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. I guess what I don't understand in this case is what you mean by `object` here. Is it the `<img>` element itself? How would you "remove" it? I can't just remove the img tag itself, because I want it to be shown very clearly to the user that a broken path exists. Is there a jQuery function I should know about here? (Also, I will try to update with some of the relevant html in the page).

Comment: I have updated my post to show the relevant HTML (the preview)

Comment: @VoidKing - OK, if you want it to show as a broken in, I've added code to my answer to do that.

Comment: I thought about that, but was hoping there was an easier way to get the browser to forget its file cache, but, I guess I knew that was a long shot. Everything on this page is set up soooo dynamically (ever-changing) that doing what you suggest won't be as easy as it sounds... Thank you!

Comment: Thing is, I would have to include client-side logic that does this as it's building the preview, but I would need server-side information. No prob, use AJAX, you say? Well, as we all know, round trips to the server are expensive, and I have built my array of objects for the client-side, just because I know AJAX is too slow for this live preview. Not sure how to handle this one, really. My users may just have to live with this little bug...

Comment: @VoidKing - what server side information is needed to do this?  The user chose to remove an image from the browser, right.  So, everything should be known right on the browser to remove the preview image too.

Comment: Well, yes, but... I suppose it is how I have this setup that is making this tougher than it should be. The server-side information I am referring to is what files actually exist in the directory at the time the preview is updated. In any event, I guess server-side information isn't really *needed* but would just make my life a lot easier. Anyway, that's okay, thanks for answering the question and helping me get to the bottom of this.

Comment: So, returning just to say a few things for the sake of future viewers:  The only trouble I was having with this answer (which, I assure you, is the correct answer to this) was that users could post and delete files at will (with AJAX, so as to not reload the page), but the browser was caching and still showing the image in a preview, when what I really wanted to show was a broken image if the file was, indeed, not there. I could mark up the page as its being written with hidden input fields showing all the files in the given directory at load up, except that would change after the page was...

Comment: ...loaded. That was the "server-side" information to which I was referring. However, I overlooked the obvious: I had a container showing the user all the "current" files. So I just used that, pushed all the values live into the array and tested with `jQuery.inArray`, and finally adjusting the script to add "bustedImg.jpg" instead of the actual file path (as this answer suggests) while updating the preview. In short, any problems I had with this answer were my own. This answer is very correct and I am convinced it is *the* best way to handle this sort of problem. Thanks again, jfriend00 :)

Comment: P.S. Using the obvious solution (AJAX again) to check the directory during each preview update, was not an option as the live preview updater would operate too slowly. Taking round-trips to the server is the amazing feature provided by AJAX, but it is expensive...